# LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'opencv_calib3d2411d.obj'

Tags: opencv

Hiii....
I am using opencv-2.4.11 with microsoft visual studio 12 express edition with fake key and windows 8.1.
I have no problem in compiling my code but when I build my project it is showing following error
" LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'opencv_calib3d2411d.obj' ".
I have added all the librarys,paths and input correctly, I am still facing the problem. Please help me resolve the problem. 
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

The input files are correct but you need to give the full path in Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies. i will show you how.

```
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_calib3d2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_contrib2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_core2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_features2d2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_flann2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_gpu2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_highgui2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_imgproc2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_legacy2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_ml2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_objdetect2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_ocl2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_photo2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_stitching2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_superres2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_ts2411d.lib

C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_video2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_videostab2411d.lib
```

Also in Linker->General->Use Library Dependency Input, Click on yes
This should certainly help.